# In UNIX/Linux, how can I display a list of all the directories in a directory using absolute path?

Tags: linux, unix, directory, command

I do not want to display files, only directories.
I found out that I can display all of the directories in my current working directory by entering

```
 ls -d */
```

But I don't know how to specify another directory.
Also I do not want to use relative path, I want to use absolute path so that I can put it in a script that I can run and it will work no matter what location I run it from.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This is a programming question because the command is a snippet of code used to write a script which can be executed on UNIX or Linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

`find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type d` will do that for you. 
`-type d` specifies you want only directories 
`-maxdepth 1` prevents it from going recursive
`$(pwd)` gives it the absolute path as the reference point, but if you have some folder, say `/batch/operation/home` - then you could do that, and it'll still print the absolute path.

If you prefer, you could alias it, or make that a function in your script to make usage a bit cleaner

```
alias lsd="find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type d"
```

Comment: Replace `$(pwd)` with the absolute path.  The OP does not want the working directory to be relevant.

Comment: `$(pwd)` is what makes it print the absolute path. Try it yourself. But good point, I should clarify...

Comment: `$(pwd)` prints the absolute path of the directory from which the command is executed, which is exactly what the OP does *not* want.

Answer (score -1):

I searched some more forums online and I found this solution, which I think is a little more straight forward:
     find /home/israel/sales -type d -print

This is my path listing, but anyone could use their own absolute path for whatever folders they have.  In my case, this lists all of the folders in the /home/israel/sales foler.
I tried it out and it worked for me :)